# DQL function that ignores accents?

Tags: sql-server, dql, documentum

Is it possible in DQL to do a LIKE query that ignores accents? Searching for a word that has an accent should return accented and non accented versions.

My question is similar to [this one in the emc forums](https://community.emc.com/message/61226#61226). Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with solution for this kind of requirement at DQL/translated SQL level.

Maybe you could write your views, and maybe you could write procedures at DB level to achieve this, but this wouldn't be clean solution. 
Maybe if you could specify your client over you execute your DQL it could be more clearer what could be done at client level.

I remind you that DQL queries depends on translation to underlying DB SQL flavor. If there are known solutions at DB level, maybe you could use them for your specific situation. Try adding new tags on your question regarding underlying DB.